# Use ng-repeat filter in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an directive for repeat my products and it's work fine. but i want add some filter add to it.

**Here is my directive code:**

```
app.directive('product', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            products: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var template =
                '<ul>' +
                    '<li data-ng-repeat="product in products>' +
                        '{{product.productName}}' +
                    '</li>' +
                '</ul>';

            // Render the template.
            element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
        }
    }
}]);
```

When i add directive to my html, show me wired error!

```
<product products="products | filter:{mainCategoryID : category.categoryID}:true"></product>
```

error in console:

[image]

How i can fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show us your `weird error!` ?

Comment: @BABU  I add screenshot of error.

Comment: @PraveshKhatri added

Answer (score 3):

try this

```js
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
  ])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
    var self = this;
  
     self.products = [{"productName":"a","id":12},{"productName":"b","id":"34"}];
}])
.directive('product', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            products: '=',
            ngModel : '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var template =
                '<ul>' +
                    '<li data-ng-repeat="product in products |filter:{id:ngModel}">' +
                        '{{product.productName}}' +
                    '</li>' +
                '</ul>';

            // Render the template.
            element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div class="main-content" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="Main as myCtrl">
      <div>
         <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.pID" />
           <product  products="myCtrl.products " ng-model="myCtrl.pID"></product>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the `pID`?

Comment: nope. it's does't work! I want filter be changeable in html code. like that one I share on first post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a directive. Use filter in your `ng-repeat`

```
<div data-ng-repeat="product in products | filter: checkId"></product>
   <ul>
       </li>
           {{product.productName}}
       </li>
   </ul>
<div>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.checkId = #you can do whatever you wanted to.
```

Comment: dude. I want be a directive!